# Image upload in ADF application

Tags: glassfish, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am in a distress on getting the solution to this problem. I have an ADF 11.1.2.3 Fusion application, on which i've set some inputUpload components that are use to upload documents of images. Everything seems to work pretty well while deployed in ADF's integrated application server (WebLogic). But when i go on production (i.e. the app is deployed on Glassfish 3.1.2), it generates some really weird errors like follows:

```
    org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.FileUploadConfiguratorImpl beginRequest
SEVERE:
java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler._readLine(MultipartFormHandler.java:252)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler._readLine(MultipartFormHandler.java:236)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler._skipBoundary(MultipartFormHandler.java:222)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:101)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:74)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.java:107)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl._startConfiguratorServiceRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:469)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:206)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:124)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
at org.jboss.seam.debug.hot.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:68)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:80)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:154)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:260)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:331)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:493)
at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:60)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This happens each time i try to upload smthg and only on Glassfish. It seems like the error is linked to the file size, but i've already set up the required configuration and the files are really small. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug on that the version of Glassfish server you are using. Check this listed bugs for reference: [TRINIDAD-10033](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD-1033)
 && [GLASSFISH-18446](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18446). You have just to upgrade from 3.1.2 to 3.1.2.2 as it is fixed on the later.